# how to get difference between two values in single arraylist?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I have arraylist like `{23,45,44,78}`. I have tried to get value at particular position and get difference of two but is there any best way to get diference of `23-45`, `45-44` and so on

Comment: Update your question with the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-Java 8 way of doing this would be to just use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < list.size()-1; ++i) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i) - list.get(i+1));
}
```

### Demo

There might be a slightly more compact way of doing this using streams.